# How to know "Why application is closing"?

Tags: c++builder

Back in BCB3 or BCB5, I seem to remember that there was a way to see why my app was closing. I would like to show a dialog box if the user closes it, but just gracefully close if the computer is rebooting. How can I know the reason for the shutdown of my app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To differentiate the reason, you will have to manually intercept and handle the `WM_(QUERY)ENDSESSION`, `WM_SYSCOMMAND`, and `WM_CLOSE` window messages directly.

Though, at least in this case, `WM_(QUERY)ENDSESION` should suffice. You can have it set a flag that you can then look at in the Form's `OnCloseQuery` event, eg:

```
class TMyForm : public TForm
{
__published:
    ...
    void __fastcall FormCloseQuery(TObject *Sender, bool &CanClose);
private:
    bool SystemIsShuttingDown;
protected:
    virtual void __fastcall WndProc(TMessage &Message);
    ...
};
```

```
void __fastcall TMyForm::FormCloseQuery(TObject *Sender, bool &CanClose)
{
    if (!SystemIsShuttingDown)
    {
        // display dialog....
    }
}

void __fastcall TMyForm::WndProc(TMessage &Message)
{
    if (Message.Msg == WM_QUERYENDSESSION)
        SystemIsShuttingDown = true;
    else if (Message.Msg == WM_ENDSESSION && Message.WParam == FALSE)
        SystemIsShuttingDown = false;
    TForm::WndProc(Message);
}
```

Comment: Discovered that: If you use Application->Terminate(), this doesn't work. It does work with Close() on the form.

Comment: @JKofsky `Application->Terminate()` simply posts a `WM_QUIT` message to the main message queue, and then the message handler sets the `Application->Terminated` property to true, which causes the message loop in `Application->Run()` to exit. Any Forms that are still active will be destroyed during process cleanup, no events fired for them. Closing the `Application->MainForm` will call `Application->Terminate()` after firing its `OnClose(Query)` events.